# Use ZRANGEBYSCORE to get the 5 highest scores - Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Looking to retrieve the five highest scores from a ZSET in redis. Checking ZRANGEBYSCORE, it looks like I can use `+inf` to retrieve the highest score, but not sure if there is a easy way to retrieve the next four highest scores. I don't know any of the scores.

My purposed solution would be something similar in SQL to `ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5`

Comment: Have you looked at [`ZREVRANGEBYSCORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore)?

Comment: Looks exactly like what I need, suppose I missed that when trying to find my solution.

Comment: Cool - you can, of course, also do `ZRANGEBYSCORE -4 +inf` as well

Comment: @ItamarHaber could you write answer instead of comment.

Comment: @RyanLitwiller could you get answer as answer and accept it instead of comment.

Comment: @NuriYILMAZ ok, and corrected a mistake I think :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Redis equivalent should be:

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE myzset 0 4
```